# PHP - Execute SQL calling function does not work

Tags: php, sql, function

I'm new to PHP, I have no clue what I'm doing. I'm trying to perform an insert into my MSSQL database. Not really sure why this is not working.

```
function Register_WBG_Tester($Email, $FullName, $ChatHandle, $Product, $PreferedGenre, $PreviousTester, $AgeGroup, $PlayTime, $Discord, $NDA)
{
    sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors',0);
    $query;
    $result;

    $query = (string)"
    DECLARE @Response AS BIT = 0;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Email FROM [dbo].[WBG_Tester] WHERE [Email] = $Email) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[WBG_Tester]
               ([Email]
               ,[Full_Name]
               ,[Chat_Handle]
               ,[Product]
               ,[Prefered_Genre]
               ,[Previous_Tester]
               ,[Age_Group]
               ,[Play_Time]
               ,[Discord]
               ,[NDA_Agreement])
         VALUES
               ($Email
               ,$FullName
               ,$ChatHandle
               ,$Product
               ,$PreferedGenre
               ,$PreviousTester
               ,$AgeGroup
               ,$PlayTime
               ,$Discord
               ,$NDA
               )

        SET @Response = 1
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SET @Response = 0
    END

    SELECT @Response"

    $result =(bool)mssql_query($query);

    return $result;        
}
```

I've never worked with PHP before, mostly work with .Net I would prefer to exec calling a stored proc rather then string query. Any help would be great. Everything I've found was for MySQL. seems to be preferred for PHP.

Comment: Q: Does it work without the use of the function?

Comment: You mean directly in SQL?

Comment: You should upgrade your driver and use error reporting. `$Email` and all other strings would need to be quoted. Also `mssql_*` is in the same boat at `mysql_*`, `Warning This function was REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.`

Comment: I mean, run your code without using the custom function.

Comment: There's a syntax error in the code you posted. Have you turned on error reporting? If you're unsure how to check for errors, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: @user3783243 They are not using mysql_, but MSSQL. Different animal ;-)

Comment: Using Word press would I still have a php.ini file? Using blue host

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner But the same in PHP 7 terms because both have been removed.

Comment: Might be dumb question do you have try & catch in PHP and print the error?

Comment: In my previous comment I gave you a link to a post that contains instructions on displaying errors, did you check that out?

Comment: @El_Vanja I did but this is for Wordpress I asked does wp have a php.ini file no response. According to research because its wp it may not have one.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. The answer there specifies you can do this in `htaccess` instead. You're missing `;` at the end of your SQL string, did you accidentally leave it out in the question or is this error in live code too?

Comment: @El_Vanja I added the missing ; still not working

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can execute store procedures in php

```
sqlsrv_prepare ( resource $conn , string $sql [, array $params [, array $options ]] ) : mixed
```

Prepares a query for execution. This function is ideal for preparing a query that will be executed multiple times with different parameter values.

```
$sql = "EXEC stp_Create_Item @Item_ID = ?, @Item_Name = ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Your code is fail!";
    die;
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    //Stuff
}
```

For more details please visit, php [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php).